# mpdf generating blank page without showing error

Tags: html, mpdf

I have created Html content using an editor and wanted to download that content in pdf format using mpdf library, but mpdf generated a blank page and it doesn't show any error, I have checked the tag of HTML is closed properly.here the $value['templateContaint']'s data coming from the editor .

```
foreach ($templateData as $key => $value) {

    ob_start();
    $mpdf = new Mpdf(['mode' => '0','format' => 'A4','margin_left' => 15,'margin_right' => 15,'margin_top' => 10,'margin_bottom' => 10,'margin_header' => 10,'margin_footer' => 10]);
    $mpdf->debug = true;
   
   
   ob_clean();
   $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
   
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($value['templateContaint']);
    
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    
    $mpdf->Output('./public/media/letter_management/ '.$templateTypeData[0]['templateName'].'_'.$value['empId'].'_'.date('Ymd').'.pdf', 'F');

}
```

```html
<div><span id="docs-internal-guid-9c95ba87-7fff-7e55-0d79-fbaf3d96753d"><p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.2; margin-left: -90pt; text-indent: -90pt; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt 90pt; text-align: right;"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;"><span style="border:none;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;width:263px;height:66px;"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9PONnqNL7puPuIJUhPrFTueBGtzZyin2DmLoEeAICZJo_pp-lH-orBpopKHk6OHEzzYQbccrAbS6NR_SBnIcde7MUcVQLQh9hVzD8Mmurlez0BFVUPTT4FPHKMgIytIFQi5kLpRyQtGAyUIj9Q" width="263" height="66" style="margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;"></span></span>
  </p>
  </span>
</div>
<div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><b>{Reference_No}</b><br></span></div><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><b>{current_date}</b></span>
<div>
  <div><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><br></span></div>
  <div><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;">To,</span></div>
  <div><b style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;">{candidate_name}</b></div>
  <div><span style="font-weight: bold;"><font face="Calibri, sans-serif" size="3">{Address_1}</font><br><font face="Calibri, sans-serif" size="3">{Address_2}</font><br></span></div>
  <div><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium; font-weight: bold;">{Address_3}</span><span style="font-weight: 700; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><br></span></div>
  <div><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-decoration-line: underline; font-size: medium; font-weight: bold;"><center style="text-align: center;">Subject: Offer Letter</center></span></div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><b>Dear</b>&nbsp;<b>&nbsp;</b><font style="font-weight: bold;">{candidate_name},</font></span></div>
  <div><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;">This has reference to your application and subsequent discussion you had with us. We are pleased to offer you the agreed position of <b>{Designation}</b>,<span style="font-weight: 700;">&nbsp;</span>
    <span
      style="font-weight: bold;">{Department}</span><span style="font-weight: 700;">&nbsp;</span>in our organization on the terms and conditions mutually discussed and agreed upon.</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><br></span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;">You are requested to bring with you the following documents (original together with one photocopy each) at the time of joining your duties:</span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><style="margin-left:100px;">1. Proof of age- either Birth Certificate, SSC Certificate, or any other acceptable document</style="margin-left:100px;"></span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><style="margin-left:100px;">2. Relieving Certificate &amp; Service Certificate from your present employer  </style="margin-left:100px;"></span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><style="margin-left:100px;">3. Educational Certificates including mark sheets</style="margin-left:100px;"></span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><style="margin-left:100px;">4. Four copies of your recent photograph in passport size </style="margin-left:100px;"></span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><style="margin-left:100px;">5. Residence proof and Identity Proof (Copy of PAN card / Passport / Driving License / Election photo identity / Aadhar Card or any other proof issued by State / Central Government)</style="margin-left:100px;"></span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><style="margin-left:100px;">6. Copy of current salary slip and Appointment Letter / latest Increment Letter</style="margin-left:100px;"></span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><br></span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;">As discussed, you shall join us before&nbsp;<span style="font-weight: bold;">{date_of_joining}</span>. A detailed Appointment Letter shall be issued to you after your joining. In case
      you fail to join within the stipulated period, the offer will stand withdrawn automatically.</span>
    </div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;">Please acknowledge receipt of this offer letter by sending back a duly signed copy as a token of your acceptance.</span><br></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><br></span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;">You are also requested to provide us a copy of your resignation letter within 3 days of receipt of this offer letter</span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><br></span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;">We are happy to welcome you to be a member of the <span style="font-weight: bold;">Loxim</span> family and look forward to a long and mutually beneficial association. </span>
    </div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><br></span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;">With best wishes, </span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><br></span></div>
    <div style=""><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium;"><b>For, Loxim Industries Ltd.</b></span></div>
  </div>
  <div><span id="docs-internal-guid-a140a951-7fff-7fb4-3410-22ad15bba414"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 700; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;"><span style="border:none;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;width:64px;height:43px;"><img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/kMWrDhpPS-YcE1ySwJP47SUoyla0Jhs6wfVeyqBeCHaz8_F-huYboALaeYiKH692E3ZQ-OUPBBFng1R9-IvXWtAye4JEeFTtoU7SK3ApnyP3jYnKRnSQtSJe0OdGsvtZ1hsZ0V0hGySezwGZVQ" width="64" height="43" style="margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;"></span></span>
    </span><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: small;"><br></span></div>
</div>
<div><span id="docs-internal-guid-0a660945-7fff-5859-f82d-f7dd68374856"><p dir="ltr" style="line-height:1.2;text-align: justify;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 700; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Treesa Antony</span></p>
  <p
    dir="ltr" style="line-height:1.2;text-align: justify;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"><span style="text-align: left; font-size: 16px; white-space: pre-wrap;"><font face="Calibri, sans-serif"><span style="font-weight: 700;"><font color="#000000">{hrvp_Designation}</font></span></font>
    </span><span style="font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-weight: 700; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">,</span></span>
    <span
      style="text-align: left; font-size: 16px; white-space: pre-wrap;">
      <font color="#000000" face="Calibri, sans-serif"><span style="font-weight: 700;">&nbsp;{hrvp_Department}</span></font>
      </span><br></p>
      <div><br></div>
      <div><span style="font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;"><span style="" id="docs-internal-guid-576e2aa4-7fff-169c-6e37-d45d8cba5932"><p dir="ltr" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; white-space: pre-wrap; line-height: 1.2; text-align: right; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><span style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(236, 105, 48); font-weight: 700; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">&nbsp;</span>
        <span
          style="font-size: medium;"><span style="font-family: Arial; color: rgb(236, 105, 48); font-weight: 700; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">&nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: Arial; color: rgb(236, 105, 48); font-weight: 700; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">LOXIM INDUSTRIES LIMITED</span></span>
          <span
            style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(236, 105, 48); font-weight: 700; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">&nbsp;</span>
            </p>
            <p dir="ltr" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: normal; white-space: pre-wrap; line-height: 1.2; text-align: right; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(91, 91, 91); font-weight: 700; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;">Registered Office:</span>
              <span
                style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(91, 91, 91); font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;"> ONE42, South Tower 9</span><span style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(91, 91, 91); font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;"><span style="font-size:0.6em;vertical-align:super;">th</span></span>
                <span
                  style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(91, 91, 91); font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;"> Floor, Ambli Bopal Road, Bodakdev Ahmedabad 380 054, Gujarat, India.</span>
                  </span>
            </p><span style="color: rgb(91, 91, 91); font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: normal; white-space: pre-wrap; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;"><div style="text-align: right;"><span style="background-color: transparent; font-size: 8pt;">+91 79 6155 0000 . info@loxim.com . www.loxim.com</span></div>
      </span><span style="font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;"><div style="background-color: transparent; color: rgb(91, 91, 91); font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: normal; white-space: pre-wrap; text-align: right;"><span style="background-color: transparent; font-size: 8pt;">CIN : U24114GJ2003PLC042820</span></div>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</div>
<div style="background-color: transparent; text-align: right; white-space: pre-wrap; font-weight: normal; font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(91, 91, 91);"><span id="docs-internal-guid-775e482b-7fff-f527-a446-1b5df7ee01f3"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;"><span style="border:none;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;width:263px;height:66px;"><img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/sEu20rfa1gU6YuIPVUjfOGdjh6bFIUfFNATo3BoHZzwYeNgElh90HRMlZZimR6qpRbt8BqR3bOdsayYqt2O7wA9BUdGnAaxpcih48bQhvTykKZ-xwwg94AfMDs5iCVqVd77RkAbWfOXJSwd-mg" width="263" height="66" style="margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;"></span></span>
  </span>
</div>
<div style="text-align: left; background-color: transparent;">
  <div><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium; font-weight: bold;">{Reference_No}</span></div>
  <div><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium; font-weight: bold;">{current_date}</span></div>
  <div><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: medium; font-weight: bold;">{current_date}</span></div>
</div>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/blank-screen.html

Comment: as you can see I have also written debug as true, but still, it didn't show me any error, yes I read the document of mpdf, and I followed their instructions but it didn't help me not doing.

Comment: You haven't debugged enough. What about https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/logging.html?

Comment: Furthermore, your `ob_` calls do not make much sense this way. Why should they be necessary? But most importatntly, your example code is not reproducible, try to update it to a MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example